# Filtering posts on Post Administration Page by Week Number instead of by Month

Tags: posts, admin, filters

Has anyone written or can suggest a plugin that would replace the filter-by-month in the Post Administration screen with filter-by-week-number instead?

e.g. a drop down option for "Week of 05/31-06/06, 2011"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go , its something i quickly cooked up and it seems to work fine:

[image]

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: admin-filter-by-week
Plugin URI: http://en.bainternet.info
Description: answer to Filtering posts on Post Administration Page by Week Number instead of by Month
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19186/filtering-posts-on-post-administration-page-by-week-number-instead-of-by-month
Version: 1.0
Author: Bainternet
Author URI: http://en.bainternet.info
*/

add_filter( 'parse_query', 'week_admin_posts_filter' );
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'ba_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts' );

function week_admin_posts_filter( $query )
{
    global $pagenow;
    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && isset($_GET['weekly_archive-dropdown']) && $_GET['weekly_archive-dropdown'] != '') {
        $link =  $_GET['weekly_archive-dropdown'];  
        //http://en.bainternet.info/?m=2011&w=22
        $pos = strpos($link, '?m=');
        if ($pos !== false) {
            $m = substr($link, $pos + 3);
            $wpos = strpos($m, '&w=');
            $w = substr($m, $wpos + 3);
            $m = substr($m, 0, $wpos + 3);
            $query->query_vars['year'] = $m;
            $query->query_vars['w'] = $w;
            $query->query_vars['post_status'] = array('publish','pending','draft','future','private');
        }
    }
}

function hack_weekly_archives($w){
    $types = "IN('publish','pending','draft','future','private')";
    $w = str_replace("= 'publish'",$types,$w);
    return $w;
}


function ba_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts()
{
    add_filter('getarchives_where','hack_weekly_archives');
    ?>
    <select name="weekly_archive-dropdown">
    <option value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select Week' ) ); ?></option> 
    <?php wp_get_archives( 'type=weekly&format=option&show_post_count=1' ); ?>
    </select>
    <?php
    remove_filter('getarchives_where','hack_weekly_archives');
}
```

Comment: The one trick with doing it this way is that it only shows the weeks for items that are published--but not for items which are either draft or scheduled. I'm toying with it to try and see how to modify it to show weeks that are scheduled, too.

Comment: @Justin : i updated the code to show posts of all types

Comment: Thanks. It still doesn't seem to be showing the weeks in which there are only scheduled posts (e.g. no published posts). I'll look into it more tomorrow.

Comment: I think in the ba_admin_posts_filter_restrict_manage_posts, if I understand it right, wp_get_archives is only pulling weeks in which there are regular posts? and then week_admin_posts_filter is showing any posts published in those weeks. Is there any way to have wp_get_archives pull the weeks for which there are scheduled posts as well as published posts?

Comment: Instead of using wp_get_archives, I'd just make a new query object with WP_Query and build the weeks list out like that.

Comment: Let me see if i can hook into wp_get_archives query

Comment: To test, try scheduling a post about 3 months in advance--or at least in a future month in which no post is published.

Comment: success at last :) i've found the filter i needed `getarchives_where` and fixed it, it now shows future posts as well in the week list, i updated the answer

Comment: Marvelous. Works perfect. THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU. I'm so glad I found this community of folks!